# Extension that can password protect or lock certain extensions in Chrome?

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension which locks/password protects access to certain Google Chrome extensions. For example one of these extensions is my notes. I want to lock them or set a password on them. Is there any way to do that?

I use Ubuntu 14.04.My browser is google-chrome.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this and I don't think there is a way to do it. There might be and you may be using the wrong tag for this.

Comment: Do you want to lock access just through the browser? That doesn't seem very useful since the notes would be accessible by looking inside the files in your Chrome profile anyway.